# ASPX Losing Session when switching from HttpMethod POST TO Get

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, session, get

Recently I have been asked by a client to log into a legacy site using `POST` and not `GET` (from a 3rd party site), All of the needed variables are now sent within a post instead of a query string.

The problem is that upon receiving all of variables they are stored into Session and then redirected to the correct page within the application (from the logo-in Page). 
While this works perfectly while calling the page using `GET`, a `POST` call will lose all of the Session variables after

```
Response.Redirect(@"~/SOMEPAGE.aspx",false);
```

Another thing that is odd is that the Session ID will remain the same but all values will be gone.
When Using Server.Transfer the session is intact but will be lost once the `Response.Redirect` is used. (there is no option to change all of the code.)

Does any one know of a way to resolve this or some sort of a work around that might be used.

Thanks!!!

Comment: How are you storing the variables into session? I imagine you had to change from reading the values from `Request.QueryString` to `Request.Forms`, correct?

Comment: Are you doing something odd like trying to do this from within an iframe?

Comment: That is correct, if (Request.HttpMethod.ToString() == "POST") I will use the Request.Forms, this is the case where I have the problem. after I store this I will try to redirect to another page on the site and try to read the session from there (it is all gone).

Comment: Not sure I'm following your answer but the redirect is done after the session is set:                                NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form;
Session["ReceivedData"] = nvc;
Response.Redirect(@"~/Somepage.aspx",false);

Comment: The main Change between a working redirect and a non working redirect is the method call to the page from a 3rd party site (when using Post the session on Somepage.aspx will be blank, while when using get it will be full)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons this could happen.

- You are using Session.Abandon() in your code
- You are switching between a secure (https://) and insecure (http://) URL
- You have some code in your global.asax that is manipulating Session, or the .Secure or .Path properties of your Response.Cookie

**edit** http://forums.asp.net/t/1670844.aspx

Comment: Thanks, But non of the following seems to be the case (I have checked before), + if this were to effect the transfer this will effect both the call from the original GET scenario